# How to enroll in Microsoft Action Pack?

Tags: msdn

I've heard about the Microsoft Action Pack, to get Microsoft licenses for a cheaper price. How do I enroll in this program? Do I need to associate myself to a Microsoft Partner to be able to subscribe to the Action Pack?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think the best starting point would be Microsoft itself: https://partner.microsoft.com/US/40016455

Hope this helps!

Comment: Do I need to associate myself to a Microsoft Partner to be able to subscribe to the Action Pack?

Comment: Step one in subscribing is 'Join the partner program' so I'm guessing that is a 'yes'.